# Cannot find location of SQLite database file on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, sqlite

I opened a SQLite database in my project.  To see if the db was actually created I went to Data/Data to find the package name... not there.  While testing I would like the ability to delet the file.
So I added data to the db, then read it out.  This works fine, but still no file at either /Data/Data, or at /Android/Data/Data.  Is the file hidden?  Other dowloaded aps have data at /Data/Data/package/...  but not the one I wrote.  It does exist - I can read and write to/from it, but cannot find it.

//data/data/Your-Application-Package-Name/databases/your-database-name NOT THERE

Using a Samsung Galaxy Nexus for testing, not the emulator.  The Nexus does not have external SD memory card.
SQLite databases are only accessible to the creating project, but is there a tool that can access it externally?  I have sqlitebrowser (awsome) i will try if I can find the file.

I would try to Root the Nexus, but I can already see /Data/Data/ other items/Data/their data, so hopefully I do not have to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to access any contents of /data/data if you access it from adb shell without first rooting the device. Shell is considered as another app (more precisely another linux user), so it's prevented from accessing other app's data in /data/data.

Root the device or use emulator to see the data.

Personally I really recommend rooting the device for development.